# Python - how to wait for user trigger in the middle of a function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, triggers, wait

I want to prompt user to choose between yes and no in the middle of a function and then continue the function accordingly. How is it possible?

**Here is my code:**

```
def download_popup(file_name, url, size, threshold):
    root = Tk()
    label = Label(root,
                  text="The file {file} at {url} is {size}Bytes large which is larger than your threshold({threshold})."
                       "\nShall I still download it?".format(file_name, url, size, threshold))
    yes = ttk.Button(root, width=5, text="yse",
                      command=lambda: return True)
    no = ttk.Button(root, width=5, text="no",
                      command=lambda: return False)
    label.grid(column=0, row=0, colspan=2)
    yes.grid(column=0, row=1)
    no.grid(column=1, row=1)
    mainloop()

# somewhere else in the middle of a function I have:
if response.getheader('Content-Length') > setting.download_threshold_var.get():
    # I want the function to wait in this line:
    if download_popup(file, url, response.getheader('Content-Length'), setting.download_threshold_var.get()):
        out_file.write(response.read())
```

Of course my code is nonsense I just put it to show better what it is like that I actually want.

By the way I can fix it by splitting the function to 3 functions in a way that first function calls download_popup() and download_popup calls either the second or third function according to the user choice but I want a more elegant solution.

Comment: This is a Tk application. By response you need to generate something the user can respond to, like a message box he needs to click OK on. Is this what you're after?

Comment: I want a window with that text and a yes and a no button. I don't care how it's done.@kabanus

Comment: You can use tkiners `Toplevel` to create a customer pop up or you can use one of tkinters pop up methods from messagebox.

Comment: Also keep in mind if you are going to paste code it needs to run or at lest be able to attempt to run. We need things like your imports and how the function is being called on to start the Tkinter app. Having to guess at how things work makes it hard to help.

Comment: I see several problems with your code that will prevent it from working. Your lambda functions don't do what you think and will not work. You use of `.format()` is wrong. Don't put words inside of the `{}` The only time you put something inside of the curly brackets is for formatting needs. Also you cannot have 2 separate quoted string to your text line and the `.format()` will only try to work with the 2nd quoted string of text. `colspan=2` is not valid. Do `columnspan=2`

Comment: @Mike-SMT thanks mike I used messagebox and now it's working perfectly. thanks for the notes too:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use one of the predefined dialogs, such as `askyesno`. If you want your own dialog, the pattern is to create an instance of a `Toplevel`, and then call `wait_window` which will not return until the window is destroyed.

### Using predefined dialogs

In python 3, the built-in dialogs are in the sub-module `messagebox`. To ask a yes/no question you can use `askyesno`. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def download_popup(file_name, url, size, threshold):
    ...
    answer = tk.messagebox.askyesno("Confirmation", "The file...")
    if answer:
        print("you answered yes")
    else:
        print("you answered no")
```

### Creating your own dialog

The key is to create a toplevel, then wait for it to be destroyed. To get the value from the dialog, you can use a global or instance variable.

It's usually best to use a class rather than a global variable, but simplicity I'll give an answer that uses a global variable:

```
def download_popup(file_name, url, size, threshold):
    global result
    result = False

    def do_yes():
        global result
        result = True
        dialog.destroy()

    def do_no():
        global result
        result = False
        dialog.destroy()

    dialog = tk.Toplevel()
    ...

    dialog.wait_window(dialog)
    print("you chose %s" % result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `command` attribute of a `Button` widget to call a `def`.

This means you don't have to put everything on hold to get the user's answer. You can just setup two `def`'s (or one and pass in a different parameter at the start) and call them when the button's are pressed.

See below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def yes():
    print("The user pressed yes, now do something you fool!")

def no():
    print("Oh no, they pressed no. Quick, panic!")

yes = Button(root, text="Yes", command=yes)

no = Button(root, text="No", command=no)

yes.pack()
no.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you need this to be done with one function you can use something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(self, *args):
    print(boolean.get())

boolean = BooleanVar()

boolean.trace("w", callback)

yes = Button(root, text="Yes", command=lambda: boolean.set(True))

no = Button(root, text="No", command=lambda: boolean.set(False))

yes.pack()
no.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is what I meant by splitting the function to 3 functions. I'm curious if it's possible in another way.

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible, this is programming. Everything is possible with enough effort. Is there a specific reason why you need to do this within one function?

Comment: I want to do it the simplest way and I did it with tkinter messagebox.

Comment: The simplest way is subjective but using two functions is probably going to be the shortest script. And no, you haven't, your question doesn't have any reference to any `MessageBox` widgets.

Comment: @EthanField OP is saying they used messagebox because I suggested it in the comments and they used it.

Comment: Their question does not need to be updated. My suggestion in the comments for their question solved the OPs problem. Now the OP should accept an answer that best fits the resolution. As I have not provided and answer I think that Bryan's answer is the best fit for the OPs question.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I concour, Bryan's answer is the best fit.